# How can I condense my code to avoid repeating for loops?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to come up with a weekly meal menu, with data coming from two lists, one for meals and the other for the days of the week.

I was wondering if I could get some advice regarding the repetition of the 'for' loops, as I believe there might be a better way to do this.

```
"""Creating Weekly food menu by randomly selecting an item from the 
'meals' list, matching the selected item to a day-of-the-week and
printing out the weekly menu."""

import random

meals = ['Steak', 'Chicken', 'Fish', 'Hamburger', 'Taco', 'HotDog' , 
         'Bier Rocks', 'Pork']

days = ['Monday: ' , 'Tuesday: ' , 'Wednesday: ']

for num in range(1):
    meals_selected = random.choice(meals)
    print(f"The selected meal for {days[0]} {meals_selected}")

for num in range(1):
    meals_selected = random.choice(meals)
    print(f"The selected meal for {days[1]} {meals_selected}")

for num in range(1):
    meals_selected = random.choice(meals)
    print(f"The selected meal for {days[2]} {meals_selected}")
```

I would like to have a result  similar to:

```
The selected meal for Monday:  Taco
The selected meal for Tuesday:  Fish
The selected meal for Wednesday:  Hamburger
```

Comment: You can actually sample multiple values from a list via `random.sample` @RobertSalter, check my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can begin by using [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample), which will give you 3 choices without replacement from the `meals` list in one function call.

You can also shuffle your list of meals in place via [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) to induce more randomness in your menu

```
import random

meals = ['Steak', 'Chicken', 'Fish', 'Hamburger', 'Taco', 'HotDog' , 'Bier Rocks', 'Pork']

days = ['Monday' , 'Tuesday' , 'Wednesday']

#Shuffle the meals
random.shuffle(meals)

#Choose 3 choices
day_meals = random.sample(meals,3)

#Print day and respective Choice
for idx in range(3):
    print(f"The selected meal for {days[idx]}: {day_meals[idx]}")
```

The output will be

```
The selected meal for Monday: Steak
The selected meal for Tuesday: HotDog
The selected meal for Wednesday: Fish

The selected meal for Monday: Pork
The selected meal for Tuesday: Hamburger
The selected meal for Wednesday: Chicken

......
```

You can easily extend this example to include menu of all 7 days, by just taking 7 samples from `random.sample`

```
import random

meals = ['Steak', 'Chicken', 'Fish', 'Hamburger', 'Taco', 'HotDog' , 'Bier Rocks', 'Pork']

days = ['Monday' , 'Tuesday' , 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

#Shuffle the meals
random.shuffle(meals)

#Choose 7 choices
day_meals = random.sample(meals,7)

#Print day and respective Choice
for idx in range(7):
    print(f"The selected meal for {days[idx]}: {day_meals[idx]}")
```

The output will be

```
The selected meal for Monday: Fish
The selected meal for Tuesday: Pork
The selected meal for Wednesday: Steak
The selected meal for Thursday: Bier Rocks
The selected meal for Friday: HotDog
The selected meal for Saturday: Taco
The selected meal for Sunday: Hamburger
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for taking the time to help me and to explain this issue to me  - this was very kind of you. I have learned so much.

Comment: Great! Glad to help! @RobertSalter :) Please consider marking my answer as accepted by clicking the tick next to the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can loop for days.

```
import random

meals = ['Steak', 'Chicken', 'Fish', 'Hamburger', 'Taco', 'HotDog' , 'Bier Rocks', 'Pork']

days = ['Monday: ' , 'Tuesday: ' , 'Wednesday: ']

for day in days:
    meals_selected = random.choice(meals)
    print(f"The selected meal for {day} {meals_selected}")
```

Result:

```
The selected meal for Monday:  Chicken
The selected meal for Tuesday:  Pork
The selected meal for Wednesday:  HotDog
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to my issue. Great learning experience.

Answer (score 2):

In case you wanted to avoid repeating the same menu in the week:

```
import random

meals = ['Steak', 'Chicken', 'Fish', 'Hamburger', 'Taco', 'HotDog' , 'Bier Rocks', 'Pork']

days = ['Monday' , 'Tuesday' , 'Wednesday']

random.shuffle(meals)
for day, meal in zip (days, meals):
    print(f"The selected meal for {day}: {meal}")
```

Comment: Thank you. Looking forward to exploring the zip function.

Comment: Please accept one of the given answers by ticking it